# I am having problems after upgrade

Tags: upgrade, 13.10

Hi i am a newbie and am having problems after I have upgraded from Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10 the menu does not work and the bar on the top is not showing. The only way to get the computer to work at all is to log differently where the graphics are not as good and then it does not work properly.